# Executing fortran code doesn't work under geany in windows 7

Tags: windows, fortran, geany

I'm having trouble getting a simple piece of fortran90 code to work. Here is the code for helloworld.f90:

```
PROGRAM hello
 IMPLICIT NONE

 PRINT *,"Hello world!"

END PROGRAM hello
```

When I compile and build, there are no errors. But as soon as I click on execute, this error appears in the command prompt:

```
'"./helloworld"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How do I get it to work? I'm using geany as an IDE, and when using Ubuntu linux it works just fine. It's when I run it under windows 7 that I get this problem. These are the compile and build commands:

```
Compile: gfortran -Wall -c "helloworld.f90" (in directory: C:\Users\Eddy\Documents\Code\Fortran)
Build: gfortran -Wall -o "helloworld" "helloworld.f90" (in directory: C:\Users\Eddy\Documents\Code\Fortran)
```

Comment: Try compiling it under the command line, so as to eliminate the "geary" factor in the problem. Then executing it. If/after that works you know the problem is in geany. If not, the problem is in your gfortran install. Because the error you get is not a gfortran message, but geany's message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I didn't have the fortran compiler installed after all! I followed the instructions from [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started) to install it.

Comment: I would have thought the lack of fortran compiler would have showed up as a compiler error

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with your Geany.

```
./helloworld
```

will not work under Windows. It's from *nix world.

Instead of Geany you can use any text editor with Fortran support (for Windows take a look at [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/), [Programmer's Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/)). Or use Geany as editor but do compilation and execution from command-line.

If you want an IDE install [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) and then [Photran](http://www.eclipse.org/photran/).